# Extrapolate data from condensed entries

Tags: excel, excel-formula, sumifs, named-ranges

I need to generate a table based on a set number of variables that will be populated with data from an existing table.
Data on the existing table looks like this:

[image: table screenshot]

I need to use this data to populate a table that will vary between 28 and 92 columns wide. I have four tables identical to the one above, that are populated by different users in 4 locations. I set up named ranges to use this data for other tasks and they work fine. However they have so far only been used to look at data 1 month at a time. I need to look at this data day by day in this table. My initial thought was as follows:

```
=SUMIFS(amount,damon,"="&[Cell Reference with date.],type,[Cell Reference with Equipment Type].
```

amount is the named range for the right most column in the image above, damon refers to the cell to its immediate left, and type refers to the equipment type definied outside of the screenshot.

I have two problems, but have only reached one. Firstly, I get nothing from the above snippet above. If I alter the damon criteria as so `damon, "<="&[Cell Reference with date.]` I get a figure which I presume is all data from the start of the table, up to the defined date. I believe this may be related to my second issue which is that, as some of the equipment is offline for multiple days at some locations, the duration is spread across multiple dates. Therefore extracting the data from the damon range could throw out a result greater than 24hrs which would render the table useless for a day by day graph comparing availability with contractual minimum.

So finally is there a way I can use the data above, for example an entry starting at 24/01/23 10:00 and ending at 28/01/23 12:00 (would present as 28/01/23 ¦ 98.00 in their respective columns) in a table that looks like this:

[image]

I am not concerned about needing to create new named ranges or extract the data into another table first then write to this table. It is worth noting the table is populated based on a user entry. It starts at the first of the month that the user defines and ends either 1,2 or 3 months later based on user input (hence 28 to 92 columns).